# Is there way to store an array with reccurring values at different indices in C?

Tags: arrays, c, linked-list

I am creating a Hangman Project in C, where the word to be guessed is represented by dashes that are replaced with correct guesses as the game progresses. I used a linked list to store all of the words. I have figured out almost all of the functions however, my latest version of the game runs perfectly unless there is a recurring character in the word to be guessed. This occurs because I created a function that takes a guess from the user and compares it to the secret word. If the guess is correct on a specific index of the "secret" string, it sets the index of the char array of the dashes to that same guess(and displays the dashes for the player to guess). The problem is the dashes string is an array and if a character occurs twice it messes up the length of the dashes.

I'm not sure what to do from here. Is there a way to store a recurring value at two different indices or should I try a different method to store the string? Also if the question is confusing it may help to read the program and understand the code a little bit. I have formatted it with comments at every function so it shouldn't be too hard to understand even though my code is a bit messy. All help is greatly appreciated.

[Link to the words.txt file in case you need it](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zoiYHSFfzsQ_hGtPhzqSu8bCABV0Nawc/view?usp=sharing)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int nodeNum, chances, misses, score, corrGuess;
char* secret;
char incorrGuess[50], guess, dashes[];



/*Node of linked list*/
typedef struct node {
    char *data;
    struct node *next;
} node;

node *start = NULL;
node *current;

/*Appending nodes to linked list*/
void add(char *line) {

    node *temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->data = strdup(line);
    temp->next = NULL;
    current = start;

    if(start == NULL) {
        start = temp;
    } else {
        while(current->next != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = temp;
    }
}

/*read text file*/
void readfile(char *filename) {
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

    if(file == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }

    char buffer[512];

    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file) != NULL) {
        add(buffer);
    }

    fclose(file);
}

/*Set initial dashes string*/
void setInitDash(){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < strlen(secret)-1; i++){
        dashes[i] = '-';
    }
}

/*Generate random number between 0 and 2999*/
void randNum(int lower, int upper)
{
    srand(time(0));
    nodeNum = (rand() % (upper - lower + 1)) + lower;

}

/*Choose random node based on random number generated*/
void chooseRand(struct node* start)
{

    node* p;
    int n;
    p = start;
    for(n = 0; n != nodeNum; n++)
    {
        p = p->next;
    }
    secret = p->data;
    setInitDash();
}

/*Check guess for correct guess*/
void checkGuess(){

    int i, j = strlen(secret) - 1;
    for(i = 0; i != j; i++){
        if(secret[i] == guess) {
            dashes[i] = guess;
            score++;
        }
    }
}

/*Check if score changes*/
void checkScore(){
    if(score == 0){
        misses++;
        chances--;
        incorrGuess[misses] = guess;
    }
    else{
        score = 0;
    }
    printf("%s", dashes);
}

/*Print current board*/
void printBoard(){
    printf("__________________________________________________________________\n");
    printf("\n\nCurrent Word: ");
    checkGuess();
    checkScore();
    printf("   Chances: %d Incorrect Guesses: ", chances);
    for(int i = 0; i <= misses; i++)
        printf("%c", incorrGuess[i]);
    printf("\nPlease enter your guess: ");
    scanf(" %c", &guess);
    printf("\n__________________________________________________________________\n");
}

/*Function for if player wins*/
void winCase(){
    printf("\n\n\n\n\nGood Job! You have guessed the word correctly. Restart the program to play again!");
}

/*Function for if player loses*/
void loseCase(){
    printf("\n\n\n\n\nUnfortunately, you have run out of chances. The word to guess was %s.", secret);
}



int main(){
    int i;
    score = 0;
    corrGuess = score;
    int stillPlaying = 1;

    printf("Hello User, Welcome to Hangman\nPlease enter number of chances you would like: ");     /*Welcome Message*/
    scanf("%d", &chances);

    readfile("words.txt"); /*Readfile and choose random word*/
    randNum(0, 2999);
    chooseRand(start);
    printf("%s", secret);   /*Print secret word for easy testing*/
    printf("__________________________________________________________________\n");     /*Print first iteration of the board*/
    printf("\n\nCurrent Word: %s", dashes);
    printf("   Chances: %d Incorrect Guesses: %s", chances, incorrGuess);
    printf("\nPlease enter your guess: ");
    scanf(" %c", &guess);
    printf("\n__________________________________________________________________\n");
    while(stillPlaying == 1){       /*While loop to print board until win or lose case is true*/
        printBoard();
        if(dashes == secret){
            stillPlaying = 2;
        }
        else if(chances <= 0){
            stillPlaying = 0;
        }
    }
    if(stillPlaying == 0){
        loseCase();
    }
    else if(stillPlaying == 2){
        winCase();
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never initialized 'dashes'. Give it a size and you should be good. I plugged in 50 and the dash-replacement worked fine.
** Edit **
Thinking about it more, I recommend using malloc/calloc/realloc instead. So, declare dashes as:

```c
char *dashes;
```

Then when you need to use it, allocate space:

```c
void setInitDash() {
  int i;
  // calloc fills the space with 0x00, ensuring that your string has a null terminator
  dashes = calloc(strlen(secret) + 1, sizeof(char); 
  //I don't know why you had strlen(secret-1), strlen ignores the null terminator
  for(i = 0; i < strlen(secret); i++) {     
    dashes[i] = 'i';
  }
}
```

Another big problem with this code:

```c
if(dashes == secret)
```

Will always evaluate to FALSE, because it compares the addresses dashes and secret point to, not the values. To compare strings you either need to compare each individual array member or use the strcmp function from string.h

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried using  
` if(strcmp(dashes, secret) == 0){  
            stillPlaying = 2;  
        }  
`  
but it didn't work.

Comment: Your strings have new line characters at the end. The simplest solution is to use a length-limited string comparison with ``` strncmp(dashes,secret,strlen(secret) - 1) ```. Testing revealed another issue: the evaluation doesn't happen until your player enters *another* character after the final correct letter. That's a flow issue, it could be solved by using a do...while loop instead of a while... loop.

Comment: Also, leaving the new-lines is fine for this application, but for something bigger I would refactor the readfile function to ensure it omits them.